# Time to live on host-level akka-http client connection

Tags: scala, dns, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a service running on production, which calls a dependency service using :

> Http().newHostConnectionPoolHttps[Promise[HttpResponse]]

Each time a new stack of the dependency service is deployed, my service DNS cache is updated by setting :

> java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60")

Problem is connections inside the pool lives on forever and only resolves DNS once at initiation time. Thus it **keeps calling the old dependency stack**.

I am searching for away to set max connection's time to live.

Answer (score 2):

Akka-http has this functionality build in,
you can look those settings up in this [reference config](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/resources/reference.conf)

In short you basically have to put the following key into your config (application.conf most likely):

```
akka {
  io {
    dns {
      inet-address {

        # To set the time to cache name resolutions
        # Possible values:
        # default: sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get() and getNegative()
        # forever: cache forever
        # never: no caching
        # n [time unit]: positive timeout with unit, for example "30 s"

        positive-ttl = 20s
        negative-ttl = 10s
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And that is basically all you have to do. Connection pool TTLs are already set to sensible values by default you can find them [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.1/scala/http/configuration.html).

Comment: This only set time to invalidate time dns cache but don't affect in any way connections lifetime. 
Restating the problem, connections are never closed. There should be some way of rotating connections after sometime.